# Facebook Login is currently unavailable for this app

Tags: ios, flutter, facebook-login

I got this error when i try facebook login in the simulator, is this caused by facebook app config? How to solve it?

[image: Unavailable]

Comment: did you manage to resolve this issue ?

Comment: @sodhancha I finally resolve the issue by setup Facebook App again in developer console. Check this: https://github.com/Innim/flutter_login_facebook/issues/17

Answer (score 0):

You might've missed setting up your [Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android) and [iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios) app on Facecbook Developer page. I suggest following the installation guide on the [plugin's documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_login) for more details.